# Combinatorics question - 5 digit number.

Tags: combinatorics

ok so the question is: "How many five digit natural numbers contain the digits $0$ and $3$ (each on of them) at least once.

So I think I have an answer, but not sure if it's right:

I take all the possibilities for forming a five-digit number $9\times10^4$ 
and subtracting whole numbers that not contain $0$ or $3\times8^5$

so my answer is : $9\times10^4-8^5$.

Is it right?

thanks.

Comment: No. If you eliminate only the number having neither $0$ nor $3$, you still have the numbers containing a $0$ or  a $3$. But you only want the numbers having both digits. Additionally, you should clear, whether the first digit is allowed to be $0$.

Comment: Peter you're right....so how can I do it?

Comment: Just determine, how many numbers contain a $0$ and not a $3$ and vice versa. To get this, start with all numbers containing a $0$ and eliminate those having a $3$ (and vice versa)

Comment: Another way : Take the pairs $a-b$ with positive integers and sum not exceeding $5$. These are $1-2$ , $1-3$ , $1-4$ , $2-1$ , $2-2$ , $2-3$ , $3-1$ , $3-2$ , $4-1$ and count the numbers having $a$ zeros and $b$ threes.

Comment: Peter, by the way is it possible to do : 1*1*10^3? . that will make sure I will take 0 and 3. after that I can any number I want(10^3)

Comment: There are $11231$ numbers if $0$ is not allowed as first digit and $14670$ numbers otherwise.

Comment: Using this method, you will count some numbers multiple times. Additionally , you first have to count the number of positions the $0$ and $3$ can have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of all 5 digit numbers, $Z$ be the set of all 5 digit numbers without a 0, $T$ be the set of all 5 digit numbers without a 3, $B$ be the set of all 5 digit numbers without a 0 or a 3.

The idea is to take $|X|-|Z|-|T|+|B|$. Adding back the $|B|$ corrects for the fact that these numbers were eliminated twice.

So $9\cdot 10^4-9^5-8\cdot9^4+8^5=11231$

Comment: But in Z and T you have numbers multiple times, for example: the number 12789 not contain 3 and not contain 0 so you subtracting the same number twice

Comment: almagest started with all numbers ($0$ not the first digit), subtracted the numbers not having a $0$ and the numbers not having a $3$ , then he added the numbers having neither $0$ nor $3$ because they were elminiated twice.

Comment: 12789 appears in X, Z, T and B. So you end up not counting it.

Comment: right. thank you both ! :)

Comment: You can interprete the formula as $9\cdot10^4-(9^5+8\cdot9^4-8^5)$, if this helps. In this case, the number having neither $0$ nor $3$ are subtracted.

Comment: great Peter. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the case, $0$ is allowed as first digit, you calculate $$10^5-9^5-9^5+8^5=14670$$